# two perpendicular vectors to one vector would be parallel?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

[image]

See the 5th-7th line.

Why would this work even for dimension >2 ?

Comment: It is true for every curve $C$ not just one.

Comment: @podiki can you elaborate more please? Won’t it be possible that they go like three vectors of a standard basis ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the set $S$ is the collection of points determined by the constraint $g(x)=c$ and $c$ is a regular value of $g$, then it has codimension $1$. That means $S$ would be a curve in the plane, or a surface in three dimensional space, etc.

Thus the tangent space of $S$ at each point is $n-1$ dimensional and one may obtain tangent vectors at a point $\bf{r}_0\in S$ as the derivative of a curve passing through this point. The argument shows that for any curve (and correspondingly any tangent vector $\bf{r}'$) you will have that $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ are both orthogonal to $\bf{r}'$. Since they are both orthogonal to the same $n-1$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ they must lie in that last remaining dimension and hence be parallel.

Comment: But the curve is not given by $g(x)=c$, rather by a parametrized vector $r(t)$ and thus is 1 dimensional?

Comment: Each curve is $1$ dimensional, but this is true for all curves on the constraint manifold $S$. Suppose for example that $S$ is a sphere and we are looking at the north pole. There are many curves passing through the north pole and the tangent vectors form the tangent plane there. If a vector is orthogonal to that plane it must be pointing straight up or down. In the posted picture the key is the phrase "for every such curve $C$".